# Python before booting?

Tags: python, boot

I was on freelancer website and I found this work proposal:

> Project Description
>
> Hello
>
> We need experience developer in python.
>
> Only bit that person who has a experience in python and Linux.
>
> I want to execute python code in Booting time before execute Operating
>   System Desktop.

I know that unless I candidate, I won't have any detail about the project, but anyway it seems odd to me.

From my understanding python is interpreted, which means that it needs a virtual environment, and that's what makes it platform independent. Therefore how can a python script (which doesn't convert 1:1 to machine instructions) run before the operative system? Since I know little about what's going on at boot time (I guess some pre-defined instructions laying in the motherboard ROM are executed, then the bootloader loads in the RAM the OS, and the program counter holds the address for the entry point of the OS itself, but I am just supposing) I ask you whether such a thing could be possible.

Comment: Those voting to close... how does this not "directly involve tools used primarily for programming."?

Comment: @Sayse what are you referring to?

Comment: @FrAxl93 - You won't notice them since you're < 3k reputation, but some users have voted to close this question for a reason that I don't understand, the comment was more for them since (to me) this looks like a valid question

Comment: Oh @Sayse thanks for defending my question! I think that it is about programming, since to me the answer may involve some explanation about how python is interpreted.

Comment: Well, I voted as "too broad" which it is. At the very least, there should be some more information about what kind of pre-boot situation we are talking about.

Comment: I agree, it may have an interesting answer. Just fyi, although it has been closed now, users can vote to reopen it

Comment: I think that the answer of Adam Adair could have been a good starting point for an interesting explanation, but anyway.. I will check the concept of runlevels on my own. And @Sinan I said that I can't provide any further detail, since this is the only description of the project. Probably I should have posted it on Quora?  What is your suggestion?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific and concrete programming questions which can be answered rather for extended discussions based on hypothetical situations. The official statement is "*This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.*" See [Stackoverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you would like to learn how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: How in the world this could have been a chit-chat question? It was clear and it admitted a simple answer: either "yes you can run a pytohn script because [...]  But with some special [...]  Here's an example [...] " or " no you can't because [...] " as in part Adam did.. Therefore it wasn't so impossible to answer, wasn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Linux, being a UNIX type OS, has the concept of runlevels. Each runlevel has a certain number of services stopped or started, giving the user control over the behavior of the machine. As far as I know for Linux, seven runlevels exist, numbered from zero to six. The "Operating System Desktop" becomes available at run level 5. At boot time the system will pass through several other runlevels before getting to 5. At level 3 the system will be have Multi-User Mode with Networking, and this would be a good level to run what ever python script you need. Maybe check into configuring Linux init scripts.